# Xamarin Forms - How to open specific page after clicking on notification when the app is closed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, lifecycle

I'm actually working on a Xamarin Forms application that need push notifications. I use the Plugin.PushNotification plugin.

When the app is running in the foreground or is sleeping (OnSleep), I have no problem to open a specific page when I click on a notification that I receive. But I was wondering how can I do that when the app is closed. Thanks!

Comment: iOS and Android?

Comment: Yes the app (Xam Forms) is targeting iOS and Android. It does not matter to me if I have to write specific code on Android and iOS.

Comment: Any idea @TeamTam ?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the answer by myself and I want to share it in case someone needs it.

**Nota bene**: according to the official documentation of the plugin, it's [Xam.Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) that is deprecated. I use the new version of this plugin, [Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin) which uses FCM for Android and APS for iOS.

There is no significant differences to open a notif when the app is running, is sleeping or is closed. Just add the next callback method in the **OnCreate** method (MyProject.Droid > MainApplication > OnCreate) and **FinishedLaunching** method (MyProject.iOS > AppDelegate > FinishedLaunching):

```
CrossPushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
{
    // manage your notification here with p.Data
    App.NotifManager.ManageNotif(p.Data);
};
```

**Common part**

*App.xaml.cs*

```
// Static fields
// *************************************

public static NotifManager NotifManager;

// Constructor
// *************************************

public App()
{
    ...
    NotifManager = new NotifManager();
    ...
}
```

*NotifManager.cs*

```
public class NotifManager
{
    // Methods
    // *************************************

    public void ManageNotif(IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        // 1) switch between the different data[key] you have in your project and parse the data you need
        // 2) pass data to the view with a MessagingCenter or an event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no succinct answer for either platform. Generally speaking, you need to tell the OS what to do when it starts the app as a result of the push notification. On both platforms, you should also consider what API level you are targeting, otherwise it won't work or even crash the app.

On iOS, you will need to implement this method in AppDelegate appropriately: `FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)`. The `launchOptions` will have the payload from the push notification for you to determine what to do with it (e.g. what page to open). For more information on iOS, [Xamarin's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vsmac#handling-foreground-app-notifications) is a good place to start.

Android has a more complicated topology in terms of more drastic differences between API levels, whether you are using GCM/FCM, as well as requiring more code components. However, to answer the question directly, you will need to handle this in `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of your main Activity. If you are using Firebase, the push notification payload is available in `Intent.Extras`. Again, [Xamarin's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin#implement-client-app-code) has a good walkthrough.

Finally, note that the `Plugin.PushNotification` library you are using has been deprecated. I suggest you either change your library and/or your implementation soon. Part of the reason that library has been deprecated is because Google has deprecated the underlying Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service, which will be decommissioned on April 11, 2019.

Comment: According to the official documentation of the plugin, it's not Plugin.PushNotification that is deprecated but Xam.Plugin.PushNotification: https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification